# bsmultiselect Select one option at a time on div

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bsmultiselect

I was trying to use "setSelected" option on my multiselect, but I nnoticed that this does not work with divs (at least I couldn't reach it myself). I am trying to make two synced multiselects, using this example: https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/snippetJs.html but with the last two inputs only.

```js
var options = [


       { text: 'item1', value: 'item1'},
       { text: 'item2', value: 'item2'},

   ];


    var teste1 = null;
    var teste2 = null;
    let isTeste2 = true;
    var $testes = $('#teste1-id')
    if (isTeste2)
        $testes = $testes.add('#teste2-id')


    var install = function () {
        $testes.bsMultiSelect({
            options: options
        });
        if (isTeste2) {
            $('#teste1-id').on('dashboardcode.multiselect:change', function () {
                $('#teste2-id').bsMultiSelect("UpdateOptionsSelected");
            })
        }

    }
    install();
    
    $("#btn").click(
       function(){
          options[0].selected = true;
          var api1 = $testes.BsMultiSelect();
          api1.updateOptionSelected(0);    
       }
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@dashboardcode/bsmultiselect@0.6.28/dist/js/BsMultiSelect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<label class="control-label" for="teste1-id">Teste1</label>
    <div id="teste1-id"></div>

    <label class="control-label" for="teste2-id">Teste2:</label>
    <div id="teste2-id"></div>

<br/>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Could you help me find a solution, please?

Comment: add jQuery and BsMultiSelect libs to your snippet

Comment: I have added them (libs), now could you repeat what is wrong with it? Everithing works but there are no 'setSelected' call inside your snippet.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the libs. What I meant, was that i want to select one option at a time, not multiple ones. The "setSelected" code looked like something that would solve the problem, but it didn't got applied. I can still shove it in there if u want.

Comment: answer was updated. now setSelected shows how to "to select one option at a time, not multiple ones"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only "one select":

```js
var options = [
       { text: 'item1', value: 'item1', selected: true},
       { text: 'item2', value: 'item2', selected: false},
];

function isValidSelection(v){
    var l = options.filter(function(item){
         return item.selected==true;
    }).length;
    var r = ( !v ) || (v && l==0);
    return r;
}

var teste1 = null;
var $teste1 = $('#teste1-id')

var install = function () {
   $teste1.bsMultiSelect({
       options: options,
       setSelected: function(o,v){
           if (isValidSelection(v)){
              o.selected = v;
              return true;
           }
           else{
              return false;
           }
       }
   });
}
install();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@dashboardcode/bsmultiselect@0.6.28/dist/js/BsMultiSelect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<label class="control-label" for="teste1-id">Test it (only one select allowed)</label>
    <div id="teste1-id"></div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I will for sure test it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JulioFraga Updated. Now 'setSelected' shows how to control the count of selected items